# WCF service:Fault Exceptions vs Error Message in Response Object

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception

Fault exceptions are send by the WCF service in case of any exceptions occured in the WCf layer and I have been using it extensively in my WCf services consumed by internal applications but i am not sure of external clients.

**Scenario**

> Say i create a WCF service which is to be exposed to my clients over internet and I will be charging for each service call. There could be different error messages (Authentication Failed/Authorization failed/Validation Errors) which can be returned from Service

I am thinking on below two appraoches

**Fault Exception:** Create a Generic ErrorHandler which implements IErrorHandler to throw Fault exception for each kind of error. Client then would have to handle the fault exception at their end, seems to me a bit complex

**Response DTO:** Response DTO would have IsError, ErrorMessage, ErrorCode etc properties populated with the error details. This might be easy for customer as they will just check some bool variable to find if there was any error.

So here is the question 
Should Fault exceptions or error message inside response object be send from WCF?  What are the advantage/disadvantage of each approach?

Comment: I have rephrased the question, Let me know if it fits as per the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the project I am currently working on we are developing an API that is publicly accessible. We are creating a response DTO to pass expected error messages to the custom. Then we wrap a fault exception around everything else and log the errors with customer identifiers (apikey). The customer will get a fault exception with no real detail but using that customers apikey we should be able to find and address the specific issue.

Comment: Thanks Aaron +1, (waiting for others before accepting it as an answer) Do you send validation errors also inside the response DTO

Comment: We do send some basic validation responses based upon our business rules and what we want to reveal. However with most request we just tell them bad request object. We log the specific error and then if/when they contact us with the problem we can help them troubleshoot. However the goal is that hopefully with our code samples and documentation they will not need to do that much.